# Como hacer un instalador de mi aplicación de C# y ofrecer actualizaciones de las modificaciones que se realicen

Tags: c#

Básicamente lo que necesito es que mi aplicación pueda instalarse en varios PC por medio de un instalador, y que las actualizaciones o modificaciones que realice posteriormente, se apliquen automáticamente en los equipos que ya esta instalada, sin necesidad de tener que instalar nuevamente.
Tengo un Servidor ftp en donde puedo alojar dichas actualizaciones, o en una simple carpeta compartida siempre disponible que también ya tengo lista.

Comment: Investiga sobre ClickOnce

Comment: Mas que investigar sobre ClickOnce, es lo que debes implementar para realizar las actualizaciones. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019